# Evaluating $\int \frac{\arctan^6(3x)}{9x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int \frac{\arctan^6(3x)}{9x^2+1}dx\,.$$

**My Attempt.**

Let $u=\arctan(3x)$.  Then $du = \frac{1}{9x^2+1}(3x)^\prime = \frac{3}{9x^2+1}$ and
$$
\int \frac{\arctan^6(3x)}{9x^2+1}dx
 = \int \frac{u^6}{3}du
 = \frac{u^7}{21} + C
 = \frac{\arctan^7(3x)}{21} + C\,.
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One of the tags is solution verification.  Is that the sole intent of this post?

Comment: $\frac{\arctan(3x)^7}{21}+c$ is [correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%5Barctan%5E6%283x%29%2F%289x%5E2+%2B1%29%5D+dx)

Comment: @Gary the `solution-verification` explains the purpose, I think. The argument looks fine to me.

Comment: @gt6989b Is it the sole purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. If you want a sanity check, you can get the same result with integration by parts viz.$$u=\arctan^6(3x),\,v=\tfrac13\arctan(3x).$$